# Filling an array with pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c

I got a homework assignment, I need to fill an array with no repeat random numbers but I can´t use the [i] intentifier, instead, i need to use pointers, i started filling the array with the same number to see how pointers works; i got this code (it just excecute once the `elementOfArray = 22`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10

void initializeArray (int *arr) {
    int **elementOfArray = &arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i) {
        **elementOfArray = 22;
        elementOfArray++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    initializeArray(&arr[0]);

    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("%d\n", arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

if i delete the line `elementOfArray++;` inside the for, i can change the value of arr[0] but i can´t move to the next position, can somebody help me please? thanks

i've searched in stackoverflow, and found this table:

```
ptr++;    // Pointer moves to the next int position (as if it was an array)
++ptr;    // Pointer moves to the next int position (as if it was an array)
++*ptr;   // The value pointed at by ptr is incremented
++(*ptr); // The value pointed at by ptr is incremented
++*(ptr); // The value pointed at by ptr is incremented 
*ptr++; // Pointer moves to the next int position (as if it was an array). But returns the old content
(*ptr)++; // The value pointed at by ptr is incremented
*(ptr)++; // Pointer moves to the next int position (as if it was an array). But returns the old content
*++ptr;   // Pointer moves to the next int position, and then get's accessed, with your code, segfault
*(++ptr); // Pointer moves to the next int position, and then get's accessed, with your code, segfault
```

i've tried ptr++, ++ptr, and *ptr++ and nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elementOfArr` points to the variable `arr`. When you increment, you're creating a pointer to just pass the location of `arr`, not the next element of the array that `arr` points to. You can't dereference this pointer, since `arr` is just a single pointer, not an array of pointers.

There's no need for `elementOfArr`. Just increment `arr` and dereference that.

```
void initializeArray (int *arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i) {
        *arr = 22;
        arr++;
    }
}
```

And in the call, you can just use `arr`. When an array is used as an R-value, it decays to a pointer to its first element.

```
initializeArray(arr);
```